# Связь защищенного/реального и режима 32 бит/16 бит

Tags: ассемблер

Каким образом связаны защищенный/реальный режимы с 32/16-битными режимами работы процессора? Реальный режим = 16 бит, защищенный - 32 бита? Или нет?

Comment: 16 битного и 32 битного режима нет. Есть реальный и защищенный. В реальном режиме адреса 16 битные, в защищенном - 32 битные.

Comment: @tilin Я читал что кроме адресации меняется размерность регистров, так ли это?. Кстати а когда адресация происходит с использованием 64 битных адресов?

Comment: Да, размерность регистров то же. Еще есть так называемый длинный режим, в котором регистры и адреса 64 битные. Но это упрощенно все. Регистры, например, разделены на группы различнгого назначения (есть и 128 битные и более), а механизмы работы с памятью в двух словах описать сложнго.

Comment: @tilin В защищенном режиме адресация зависит от указаний в дескрипторе сегмента кода. может использоваться и 16 битный код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от того что понимать под 16/32 битными режимами работы. В принципе таких режимов работы не существует. Существуют такие понятия как используемый размер адресов и используемый размер операндов в инструкциях. Причем есть размер по умолчанию и эффективный размер. Префиксы инструкций 66h и 67h могут переключать используемый данной инструкцией размер операнда или адреса. Их появление в инструкции переключает размер на "противоположный" относительно "текущего размера". В свою очередь текущий размер зависит от режима работы процессора и некоторых других факторов.

В реальном режиме работы процессора по умолчанию используются 16 битные аргументы и 16 битные смещения. Однако применение префиксов позволяет переопределить для текущей инструкции как размер операндов так и размер применяемого смещения. (Для адресации за пределами 1 Mb должна быть открыта адресная линия A20)

В защищенном режиме работы процессора размер адресов и операндов по умолчанию задается битом 54 дескриптора сегмента кода, называемым битом `DB` (в других источниках `D`). Если данный бит равен 0 то применяются 16 битные размеры, если 1 то 32 битные. При этом режим адресации в сегменте стека задается отдельно, битом DB в дескрипторе сегмента стека. При DB=0 используется SP, при DB=1 ESP.

В режиме работы long mode 64-битных процессоров в дескрипторах начинает использоваться бит 55 (`L`) для указания 64 битного кода, при этом флаг DP не используется и должен быть 0 (значение 1 зарезервировано для возможного использования в будущем)

В режиме SMM (system management mode) по умолчанию используется адресация реального режима, которая так же может быть изменена с использованием префиксов инструкций.